# Command line-tool to convert geojson file to line-delimited geojson

Tags: geojson, command-line, node-js

I'm loving the [ndjson-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ndjson-cli) tools for working with newline-delimited GeoJSON files. But I can't seem to find a tool that converts a standard GeoJSON (whether minified or prettified) ond converts it to newline-delimited. Is there one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a dedicated command-line tool on NPM to do this, now:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/geojson2ndjson
```

> Usage
>
> `npm install -g geojson2ndjson`
>   `geojson2ndjson myfile.geojson | ...`
>
> Or read from standard input:
>
> `cat myfile.geojson | geojson2ndjson | ...`
>
> Examples
>
> List the properties of every feature, without the geometries:
>
> `geojson2ndjson myfile.geojson | ndjson-map d.properties`

Answer (score 11):

Borrowing from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750745/converting-comma-delimited-json-to-a-newline-delimited-node) and using the [jq command line tool](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) you can filter GeoJSON feture objects and dump them as new-line delimiter with:

```sh
cat my.geojson | jq -c ".features[]" > nld_features.json
```

The important parts here are the `-c` flag which prints compact JSON objects on a single line, and the filter `".features[]"` which selects the features object from the top level of the object, and then calls an Array/Object iterator over the values to break the features into separate JSON objects. 
 If you want to extract coordinates as well, you can use the [different filters](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters) in jq to extract the values as well.

Comment: Ah yeah. I used to use jq, but in the end I found its syntax too hard to remember, and scripts quickly became incomprehensible.

Comment: This is extremely slow for larger file sizes (I'm guessing b/c jq reads the entire file into memory ... you can the `--stream` option to improve this...

Answer (score 5):

You can use ogr2ogr:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSONSeq ~/Downloads/data.geojson.ld ~/Downloads/data.geojson
```

Comment: This helped me a lot, I was using ogr2ogr to convert PostGIS geometries into geojson but I needed line delimited version, now I use `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSONSeq regions.json.ld "PG:host=localhost dbname=mydb user=postgres password=passwd" -sql "select name,wkb_geometry from regions"`

Answer (score 4):

[Tippecanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe) also has this functionality built in:

`tippecanoe-json-tool source.json > out.nd.json`

I've only tested with small examples, but given that tippecanoe is blazing fast and built for giant geojsons, this should be a robust option. Source [here](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe/issues/634#issuecomment-415109361).

Comment: Huh, thanks. The documentation is a bit obscure, and there's no command-line help.

Comment: Note from a few years later — the Tippecanoe docs now live here: https://github.com/felt/tippecanoe#usage