# Command line-tool to convert line-delimited geojson file to regular geojson

Tags: geojson, command-line

Now I need the opposite tool from [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271012/command-line-tool-to-convert-geojson-file-to-line-delimited-geojson): something to convert a line-delimited GeoJSON file to a single GeoJSON file.

In other words:

1. Write `{ "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [` on the first line.
2. Append all the lines from the input file, with a comma at the end of all of them except the last.
3. Then write `]}`

Is there such a tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heh, predictably, I wrote one. (Added to the existing geojson2ndjson package.)

```
npm install -g geojson2ndjson
ndjson2geojson myfile.json > myfile.geojson
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/geojson2ndjson